# Why `std::i64::MIN..=-1i64` and `1i64..=std::i64::MAX` are not covered in my pattern?

Tags: rust

How to match an i64 variable against pattern of positive, zero and negative?

Say I have the following function f1, I would like to do a match, return -1 for negative input, 1 for positive input, 0 for 0.

```
fn f1(value: i64) -> i64 {
    match value {
        num if num > 0 => 1,
        0 => 0,
        num if num < 0 => -1,
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_f1() {
    assert_eq!(f1(-5), -1);
}
```

The Playground link is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55e849baf864f498a35f4a6c8b4c677d)

But it complains "error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `std::i64::MIN..=-1i64` and `1i64..=std::i64::MAX` not covered". What's the correct pattern?

Feel free to suggest better ways to write the pattern, I hope to write it in range like:

```
fn f1(value: i64) -> i64 {
    match value {
        1.. => 1,
        0 => 0,
        ..=-1 => -1,
    }
}
```

But even if I enable nightly, it still suggest "add `#![feature(exclusive_range_pattern)]` to the crate attributes to enable", which I am not sure how to do in Playground.

Comment: `num if num < 0 => -1,` can be changed to `_ => -1`, since the two earlier conditions already ensure that it is negative.

Comment: because pattern guard is an useless feature. <Insert change my mind meme here>

Comment: @loganfsmyth, thanks, this works. But it feels like a workaround against the language/compiler. I mean, my logic itself is exhaustive but they are not checked....

Comment: @Stargateur, I get the same feeling now. I just expect match to do exhaustive check, but as soon as you have match guards, you must do something to effectively catch all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plain patterns, rust can check whether the match arms are exhaustive. This is because plain patterns have a small number of forms, all of which rust has been told how to understand.

But your match arms involve `if` conditions, sometimes called guards in this context. The condition in a guard can have an arbitrary form. Some will look easy to you, but [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). No compiler, including rust's, will ever be able to predict arbitrary conditions. It's a [mathematical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems) [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). So rust does not waste its time trying.

In this particular case, there is actually a way to replace the guard with a plain pattern, which rust can check exhaustively.

```
fn f1(value: i64) -> i64 {
    match value {
        1..=std::i64::MAX => 1,
        0 => 0,
        std::i64::MIN..=-1 => -1,
    }
}
```

You could use half-open ranges, but they require unstable rust.

```
fn f1(value: i64) -> i64 {
    match value {
        1.. => 1,
        0 => 0,
        ..=-1 => -1,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised that when match guard exists, that arm with not be taken into consideration for exhaustiveness. I cannot find this in The book. Do you know any documentation for this?

Comment: Yeah, learning materials could definitely point this out explicitly. It's not really about documentation though. With a little theory knowledge, it's not surprising at all. In fact, the _opposite_ would have been surprising. I've edited the answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to write `f1` as simply as possible, there's already a function for it, and it's called `i64::signum`:

```
fn sign(x: i64) {
    println!("sign of {} is {}", x, x.signum());
}

fn main() {
    sign(-10);
    sign(0);
    sign(10);
}
```

If your goal is to write the sign comparison more generically to do something else, I'd write it like this:

```
fn sign(x: i64) {
    match x.signum() {
        -1 => println!("negative"),
        0 => println!("zero"),
        1 => println!("positive"),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

The compiler can often optimize this code reasonably well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip anyway. I am more confused why it complains my patterns being non-exhaustive while they clearly look exhaustive to me.